# Making RecyclerView image fullscreen when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to make a **recyclerview image fullscreen when clicked and display a button below as shown in this xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:id="@+id/profileButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreenView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/profileButton"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the **Image Adapter** I have so far

```
public class ImageAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
private File imagesFile;


public ImageAdapter(File folderFile)
{
    imagesFile = folderFile;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_images_relative_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    File imageFile = imagesFile.listFiles()[position];
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    holder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


}
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if(MainActivity.checkIfGalleryEmpty(imagesFile)==true)
        return 0;
    else
        return imagesFile.listFiles().length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView);

    }
    public ImageView getImageView()
    {
        return imageView;
    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure where to put the `onClickListener` methods (should it be here or in my main?) or how to implement an `onClickListener` that displays an image larger. In addition the button displayed will have to perform a function, so that will have an `onClicklistener` as well, probably in another activity file. If you have any tips or suggestions on how to implement this considering the framework I have please let me know. I am also willing to post parts of my `MainActivity` file if that helps at all.

Comment: Register your onclicklistener here imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView and open a new activity

Comment: Just set Onclick and for better effect use [shared element transition](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html).

Comment: use Zooming view (check my answer) https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface in the ImageAdapter class

```
public interface Callback {
    void onImageClicked(string imagePath);
}
```

Then add the constructor

```
Callback mCallback;
public ImageAdapter(File folderFile, Callback callback)
{
    imagesFile = folderFile;
    mCallback = callback;
}
```

Then in the Activity/Fragment from where you are calling the ImageAdapter, pass the callback and implement the callback methods, setting adapter will be same as you are using

```
ImageAdapter adapter = ImageAdapter(folderFile, this);
```

After implementing the callback method, you will find a method in the activity/fragment

```
@Override
public void onImageClicked(string imagePath) {
     //Here you can do anything with the clicked image (Show the full screen image)
}
```

Then from the adapter you can pass the imagePath to the activity from the callback

```
holder.getImageView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCallback!=null){
                    mCallback.onImageClicked(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });
```

As per my understanding your problem is how to call the onClick method. if you have doubt on how to display full screen image, you can create an another activity with the full screen imageview and set the image.

Comment: Hi, this code looks good and i'm trying to implement it, but when i put ImageAdapter adapter = ImageAdapter(folderFile, this); in my activity I get an error for the callback field that says [packagename].ImageAdapter.Callback cannot be applied to [packagename].MainActivity. Did I misunderstand what you wrote here?

Comment: Place the cursor on the line and click alt+enter, then implement the method

Comment: It gives me a few options but i casted it like this ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(GalleryFolder, (ImageAdapter.Callback) this); is that what you intended?

Comment: No bro, ok you do one thing.. Implement the Callback in the first line public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.Callback

Answer (score 1):

Register onclick in viewholder like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
private ImageView imageView;

public ViewHolder(View view)
{
    super(view);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //TODO: Zooming a View
            }
        });

}
public ImageView getImageView()
{
    return imageView;
}
}
```

To display full-size image using zooming view.

[Developer site for display fullsize image](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable click of image view in the recyclerview viewholder , on onclick pass the file path to the next activity ,there you can use full with `ImageView` for setting this image bitmap

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
 {
private ImageView imageView;

public ViewHolder(View view)
{
    super(view);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                File imageFile = imagesFile.listFiles()[getAdapterPosition()];

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,FullScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("filepath",imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);    

            }
        });

}
public ImageView getImageView()
{
    return imageView;
}
}
```

Also in the adapter class , pass the `context` to the constructor

```
public ImageAdapter(File folderFile,Context context)
{
imagesFile = folderFile;
mContext = context;
}
```